# Understanding curvature equality: $\pi^*F^\nabla=F^\omega$ using the frame bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, connections

I am trying to understand the following situation

Given a real vector bundle $E\to M$ of rank r with connection $\nabla$, and its frame bundle $\pi:Fr(E)\to M$. We can define different curvatures namely:

$$F^\omega\in \Omega^2(Fr(E),Mat_r(\mathbb{R}))$$

and $$F^\nabla\in \Omega^2(M,End(E)),$$ where $\omega=\pi^*\nabla-\varphi^{-1}\circ\nabla^{can}\circ\varphi$ with $\varphi:\pi^*E\overset{\sim}{\to} Fr(E)\times \mathbb{R}^r$.

Now I want to understand how the equality: $\pi^*F^\nabla=F^\omega$ comes to stand.

I am having trouble since I am not sure how the pullback of the curvature works, whereas the pullback of the connection is clear to me.
One question I thus have is when does $F^{\pi^*\nabla}=\pi^*F^\nabla$ hold/ does it even hold. if this were the case then I do not get how ${\pi^*\nabla}=\omega$ (since I thought $F^{\pi^*\nabla}=d\omega+\omega \wedge \omega$)

Any ideas?

Comment: Waiting for someone with more knowledge to answer, but from what I am currently learning, the first version (Lie-algebra valued 2-form over the principal bundle) satisfies certain equivariance condition with respect to the action of $GL(\mathbb{R},r)$ on the bundle and Lie algebra $Mat_r(\mathbb{R})$, and this can be seen to be a $End(E)$-valued 2-form. I am somewhat lost in your notation, though and would wait for a better answer.